# Are FFNN (MLP) Lipschitz functions?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, math

My question is regarding standard dense-connected feed forward neural networks with sigmoidal activation.

I am studying Bayesian Optimization for hyper-parameter selection for neural networks. There is no doubt that this is an effective method, but I just wan't to delve a little deeper into the maths.

**Question:** Are neural networks [Lipschitz](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LipschitzFunction.html) functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this area, but it would appear to depend on the choice of activation function:

- $e^x$ is not Lipschitz continuous. See [Analytic functions which are not Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).
- $\tanh(x)$ [is](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Sd0cCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=tanh%20lipschitz%20continuous&source=bl&ots=xgIQAQYDEw&sig=plaHUKkiPYB388sT2ht-iro6ntY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLvfyo14TPAhVmCsAKHYxXBoMQ6AEIQTAG#v=onepage&q=tanh%20lipschitz%20continuous&f=false).

That said, [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/~esontag/public_html/FTP_DIR/00cdc-papers-refs-eds/CD001925.PDF) appears to give some conditions (specifically for *dynamic* ANNs) for which networks with activation function involving $e^x$ *can* be Lipschitz continuous, so possibly the above is not the whole story.